# Linux, how using tee in piped command

Tags: linux, unix, command, tee

```
time curl http://www.google.com | tee | wc | gzip > google.gz
```

Why doesn't this command work?  It creates the file, and times the operation, but does not print the number of lines, words, and characters (wc).

```
time curl http://www.google.com | tee | wc
```

This will print print the words characters and lines, but obviously, the tee portion is pointless.

Is it because I'm sending the word count of the url to google.gz?

I have to use tee, gzip, time, curl to download google web page to a gziped file, print the word count, how long it took.

It is an assignment, so I'm not looking for someone to do it for me.  I just am having a problem in that I can't tee to utility, and I cant to and gzip at the same time.

Maybe there is a way to use gzip with curl?

Comment: All of these commands do exactly what they should do. Your first command pipes the output of `wc` to `gzip`. The empty `tee` doesn't do anything because it has no target. If you explained what it was you wanted to do, we could explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that something like this is what you want:

```
time curl http://www.google.com | tee /tmp/z | gzip > google.gz; wc /tmp/z; rm /tmp/z
```

Comment: Yes, I could have done this, but the assignment is to do this using a one line piped combination of commands.  I'm not sure that `;` qualifies?

Comment: WHY DIDN'T YOU SAY SO?! Why make us pull teeth to get the actual question? (Hint: Pipe the output of `gzip` to a `tee` that stores it in `google.gz` and allows it to continue on to `gunzip | wc`.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, `wc` outputs the number of characters, words and lines, but then [you send it to](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) `gzip` which compresses it. Eventually, compressed information ends up in `google.gz`. If you decompress the file, e.g. with

```
gunzip google.gz
```

you'll see the three numbers.

Also, normally when one uses [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee), they specify a file where the tee'ed data is supposed to be stored.

Comment: how can you do something like this : `time curl http://www.google.com | tee gzip > google.gz | wc`     Doing this just creates a file called gzip and another called google.gz.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what else one would expect. Perhaps this proves helpful: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee

Answer (score 2):

`time curl http://www.google.com | tee /dev/tty | gzip > google.gz`